# Error while drawing a ellipse with python PIL.ImageDraw

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I used this code to open a window and draw vertices for a graph in a specific place:

```
def draw_field(field):
    img = Image.new("RGB", (800,600), (255,255,255))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    for i in vertices:
        draw.ellipse((10, 10), (i[1], i[3]), fill ="blue", outline ="green")
```

and got the error:

```
ellipse() got multiple values for argument 'fill'
```

even though there was only one argument for fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're calling the function wrong. See the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.ellipse), which suggests you should pass the coordinates as two tuples inside a list:

```py
draw.ellipse([(10, 10), (i[1], i[3])], fill ="blue", outline ="green")
```

I believe what's happening is it's taking the second set of points you're passing in as the argument to `fill` and complaining that it's a 2-tuple, when it expects a string.

Comment: Yes this was exactly the problem ty so much